# Dynamically responding to an unpacking assignment statement

Tags: python, iteration, variable-assignment, abstract-syntax-tree, inspect

In an unpacking assignment statement, can the assigned object inspect the number of variables it is being assigned to?

```
class MyObject:

    def __iter__(self):
        n = some_diabolical_hack()
        print(f"yielding {n} vals")
        return iter(["potato"]*n)
```

Something like:

```
>>> x, y = MyObject()
yielding 2 vals
>>> a, b, c = MyObject()
yielding 3 vals
```

In the more general case, can it introspect the "shape" of the [`target_list`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-target-list) being used in an assignment?

```
>>> first, *blob, d[k], (x, y), L[3:7], obj.attr, last = MyObject()
unpacking to <_ast.Tuple object at 0xcafef00d>
```

*Example potential use case*: an improved `MagicMock()` which doesn't need to be pre-configured with a fixed iteration length when being used to patch out some object on the right hand side of an assignment statement.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to return a tuple and let the caller handle it? Anytime you think about putting a "diabolical hack" in your code, you should first consider refactoring it

Comment: Certainly diabolical hacks almost never have a place in production-quality code. But I do think this is an interesting question from an academic standpoint. I'd love to see an answer even if I never intend to fire that particular gun at my foot :-)

Comment: Returning a tuple only sidesteps the question (how long should the tuple returned be?).  I've edited into the question an example use-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the traceback module:

```
import traceback

def diabolically_invoke_traceback():
    call = traceback.extract_stack()[-2]
    print call[3]
    unpackers = call[3].split('=')[0].split(',')
    print len (unpackers)
    return range(len(unpackers))

In [63]: a, b, c = diabolically_invoke_traceback()
a, b, c = diabolically_invoke_traceback()
3

In [64]: a
Out[64]: 0

In [65]: b
Out[65]: 1

In [66]: c
Out[66]: 2
```

Comment: Concise and straightforward :-) it doesn't quite work on certain corner cases, like assignments with line continuations (e.g. `a,b,c = \ ` on one line, followed by `diabolically_invoke_traceback()` on the next), but my answer _also_ doesn't quite work in corner cases, so I'm not in a position to judge :-p

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer: I don't recommend using diabolical techniques in production-quality code. Everything in this answer might not work on a different computer from mine, or a different Python version from mine, or on a non-CPython distribution, and it might not work tomorrow morning.)

Perhaps you could do this by inspecting the calling frame's bytecode. If I'm reading the [bytecode guide](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html?highlight=unpack_sequence#python-bytecode-instructions) correctly, multiple assignment is handled by the instructions `UNPACK_SEQUENCE` or `UNPACK_EX`, depending on whether the target list has a starred name. Both of these instructions provide information about the shape of the target list in their arguments.

You could write your diabolical function to climb the frame hierarchy until it finds the calling frame, and inspect the bytecode instruction that occurs after the `FUNCTION_CALL` that represents the right-hand-side of the assignment. (this is assuming that your call to `MyObject()` is the only thing on the right side of the statement). Then you can extract the target list size from the instruction's argument and return it.

```
import inspect
import dis
import itertools

def diabolically_retrieve_target_list_size():
    #one f_back takes us to `get_diabolically_sized_list`'s frame. A second one takes us to the frame of the caller of `get_diabolically_sized_list`.
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_back
    #explicitly delete frame when we're done with it to avoid reference cycles.
    try:
        #get the bytecode instruction that immediately follows the CALL_FUNCTION that is executing right now
        bytecode_idx = frame.f_lasti // 2
        unresolved_bytecodes = itertools.islice(dis.get_instructions(frame.f_code), bytecode_idx+1, bytecode_idx+3)
        next_bytecode = next(unresolved_bytecodes)
        if next_bytecode.opname == "UNPACK_SEQUENCE":   #simple multiple assignment, like `a,b,c = ...`
            return next_bytecode.arg
        elif next_bytecode.opname == "EXTENDED_ARG":    #multiple assignment with splat, like `a, *b, c = ...`
            next_bytecode = next(unresolved_bytecodes)
            if next_bytecode.opname != "UNPACK_EX":
                raise Exception(f"Expected UNPACK_EX after EXTENDED_ARG, got {next_bytecode.opname} instead")
            args_before_star = next_bytecode.arg % 256
            args_after_star = next_bytecode.arg >> 8
            return args_before_star + args_after_star
        elif next_bytecode.opname in ("STORE_FAST", "STORE_NAME"): #single assignment, like `a = ...`
            return 1
        else:
            raise Exception(f"Unrecognized bytecode: {frame.f_lasti} {next_bytecode.opname}")
    finally:
        del frame

def get_diabolically_sized_list():
    count = diabolically_retrieve_target_list_size()
    return list(range(count))

a,b,c = get_diabolically_sized_list()
print(a,b,c)
d,e,f,g,h,i = get_diabolically_sized_list()
print(d,e,f,g,h,i)
j, *k, l = get_diabolically_sized_list()
print(j,k,l)
x = get_diabolically_sized_list()
print(x)
```

Result:

```
0 1 2
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 [] 1
[0]
```

Comment: Hmm, it occurs to me that this approach only counts the size of the _top level_ target list. Nested target lists, such as `(m, n, o), p = get_diabolically_sized_list()` will correctly generate a list of length two, but it won't ensure that the list's first element can unpack into three values. So this approach isn't suitable for capturing the "shape" of complex target lists.

Comment: If you keep elaborating the kind of assignments you handle, you'll end up rewriting a large subset of the python parser, which is another level of diabolicity. ;)

Comment: Very true. In the Python chat, the OP wondered whether the `ast` module might be a better way to capture the full context of the calling assignment statement. I think he's on to something there...